# First item of the Dropbox is not working when the page first load using C#

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

The first item of the Dropbox is not working when the page loaded but if select the second item in the Dropbox the form will populate with the relevant data. If I come back to first item selected previously it will work this time. Any help please. Thanks

HTML code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListUpdateSample" runat="server" Height="37px" Width="132px" CssClass="auto-style111" AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListUpdateSample_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="False">
```

C# Code

```
//Code to populate the Dropbox

     using (SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT     Patient.MBID, Sample.SampleID
        FROM         Patient INNER JOIN
          Sample ON Patient.MBID = Sample.MBID
        WHERE 
           Patient.Surname = @Surname and Patient.DOB = convert(datetime, @DOB, 103) 
                                     ORDER by Sample.SampleID ASC ", con))
      {

        cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSearchSurname.Text);

        cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtSearchDOB.Text);

         SqlDataAdapter da5 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd5);
         DataSet dt5 = new DataSet();
         da5.Fill(dt5, "Sample");
         DataTable myDataTable = dt5.Tables[0];

        // Loop to insert the Sample ID in the Drop box

         foreach (DataRow tempRow_Variable in myDataTable.Rows)
         {
            var tempRow = tempRow_Variable;
            DropDownListUpdateSample.Items.Add(tempRow["SampleID"].ToString());

        }
     }


 //Code to Populate the form after an item is selected from the Dropbox

  protected void DropDownListUpdateSample_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand st = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT    * 
                             FROM       Sample
                             WHERE
                             SampleID=@SampleID", con))
                  {

                    st.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SampleID", DropDownListUpdateSample.SelectedItem.Value);

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = st.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            txtUpdateSampleID.Text = reader["SampleID"].ToString();
                            txtUpdateSampleType.Text = reader["SampleType"].ToString();
                            txtUpdateSampleDate.Text = reader["SampleDate"].ToString();
                            txtUpdateSampleTrial.Text = reader["SampleTrial"].ToString();
                            DropDownListUpdateFirstSample.SelectedItem.Value = reader["FirstSample"].ToString();
                            txtUpdateSampleComments.Text = reader["Comments"].ToString();
                            txtUpdateSampleConsultant.Text = reader["ConsultantName"].ToString();
                            DropDownListUpdate.SelectedItem.Value = reader["Diagnosis"].ToString();
                            DropDownListUpdateConsentConfirm.SelectedItem.Value = reader["ConsentConfirmed"].ToString();
                            txtUpdateConsentDate.Text = reader["DateConsent"].ToString();
                            txtUpdateOrther.Text = reader["OtherConsent"].ToString();
                            DropDownListUpdateSectionDecline.SelectedItem.Value = reader["SectionDecline"].ToString();
                            DropDownListUpdateQuarantine.SelectedItem.Value = reader["Quarantine"].ToString();
                            DropDownListUpdateClinicalArchive.SelectedItem.Value = reader["ClinicalArchive"].ToString();
                            DropDownListUpdateResearch.SelectedItem.Value = reader["Research"].ToString();
                            //DropDownListUpdateClinicalArchive.SelectedItem.Value= reader["Research"].ToString();

                    }
                    }
                 }
          con.Close();
       }

    }
```

Comment: the `selectedindexchanged` event will not be called when the page is loaded

Comment: You should set `SelectedValue` after binding data source `dropdownlist.SelectedValue = youValue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
 public void functionForSelectedValue(int id)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand st = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT    * 
                         FROM       Sample
                         WHERE
                         SampleID=@SampleID", con))
        {

            st.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SampleID", id);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = st.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    txtUpdateSampleID.Text = reader["SampleID"].ToString();
                    txtUpdateSampleType.Text = reader["SampleType"].ToString();
                    txtUpdateSampleDate.Text = reader["SampleDate"].ToString();
                    txtUpdateSampleTrial.Text = reader["SampleTrial"].ToString();
                    DropDownListUpdateFirstSample.SelectedItem.Value = reader["FirstSample"].ToString();
                    txtUpdateSampleComments.Text = reader["Comments"].ToString();
                    txtUpdateSampleConsultant.Text = reader["ConsultantName"].ToString();
                    DropDownListUpdate.SelectedItem.Value = reader["Diagnosis"].ToString();
                    DropDownListUpdateConsentConfirm.SelectedItem.Value = reader["ConsentConfirmed"].ToString();
                    txtUpdateConsentDate.Text = reader["DateConsent"].ToString();
                    txtUpdateOrther.Text = reader["OtherConsent"].ToString();
                    DropDownListUpdateSectionDecline.SelectedItem.Value = reader["SectionDecline"].ToString();
                    DropDownListUpdateQuarantine.SelectedItem.Value = reader["Quarantine"].ToString();
                    DropDownListUpdateClinicalArchive.SelectedItem.Value = reader["ClinicalArchive"].ToString();
                    DropDownListUpdateResearch.SelectedItem.Value = reader["Research"].ToString();
                    //DropDownListUpdateClinicalArchive.SelectedItem.Value= reader["Research"].ToString();

                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }

}
protected void DropDownListUpdateSample_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    functionForSelectedValue(DropDownListUpdateSample.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

And in page load:

call

```
foreach (DataRow tempRow_Variable in myDataTable.Rows)
     {
        var tempRow = tempRow_Variable;
        DropDownListUpdateSample.Items.Add(tempRow["SampleID"].ToString());

    }
DropDownListUpdateSample.Items.FindByValue("IdforWhichYouWantTobindIt").Selected = true;
functionForSelectedValue(DropDownListUpdateSample.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @EricMbiada, if it solved your problem, please accept the answer.